# page/08140 is HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, networking, http-status-code-405

so I am trying to write to a server on port 80 with the address being "threethinggame.com", I have "page/08140" as my name variable and I am trying to contact this server but having trouble doing so as when I do I receive this:

page/08140 is HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
(Along with other stuff after)

the code I am code here:

```
sw.WriteLine("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + address + "\r\nContent-Length: 36\r\n\r\nname=" + name + "&location=" + position);
                    sw.Flush();
```

(I dont think it would format properly when I tried to put it in code sample);

when doing this, I also put location as "page/08140" too.

```
address = "threethinggame.com";
```

name = "page/08140";
location = "page/08140";

Answer (score 0):

it seems I am one of your classmates, please take a look to this image as it may help you.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMJ5H.png)